# Lightning Script SRC Attribute Rendered as DATA-SRC

Tags: javascript, lightning, static-resources

I am trying to load RequireJS, a static resource, and it is failing to load into the Lightning application because the element is rendered incorrectly.

I'm using the LTNG:REQUIRE tag in this format:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.RequireJS}" src="{!$Resource.RequireJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" />
```

However when I look at the rendered HTML I see that it is not loading as a resource in the app because it is rendering as:

```
<script data-src="/resource/.../RequireJS"></script>
```

This is causing the app to fail as there is a big dependency on this JS file. Does anyone have an idea as to why "data-src" is rendered rather than "src"?

Comment: Why are you settting src attribute instead of `<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.RequireJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" />` ?

Comment: Hi, I am not using src, i'm using <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.RequireJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" /> but it is not rendering correctly as stated in the issue. The tag should be rendered as <script src=.... but instead is rendered as <script data-src=....

Comment: I tried the same in my org its working fine and indeed it is rendered as <script data-src=.../> which not an issue at all.Are you getting any error message? Are you referencing the static resource path correctly?

Comment: Yes i'm getting an error message because a function which is in the RequireJS file is not recognized/available because the script is not loaded into the application, presumably because the src attribute is not rendered as src, but as data-src. @Praveen Are you able to use the RequireJS functions with the script referenced as data-src?

Comment: Can you check the status of the resources loaded in the *Network* tab of the chrome's developer tools ?

Comment: Yes, so it is not included in the list of resources when the app is loaded. But if I change the HTML for the script element from data-src to src, then chrome immediately includes it as a resource.

Comment: Ah, am getting an error that `require is not defined`,when i tried to reference  `require` variable afterscriptsloaded's action.

Comment: Yes that is the error I get as well.

Comment: One question, do you really need requireJS ? why not use `<ltng:require />` to loaded multiple js files like this : `scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}"`

Comment: I've tried this with JQuery as well and it renders the source for that script as data-src as well.

Comment: RequireJs is still a issue,but jQuery works for me, and make sure `initTypeahead` method is called only  by the `afterScriptsLoaded` not by other frame work event like `init`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution for me was to **disable** the new lightning security feature known as "**LockerService**" through the critical updates.

This may not be enabled in most orgs as of now, which is why this may have been a unique problem that only I was facing. But fair warning the feature will be auto-enabled for all orgs in Winter '17.

**Documentation**:
[Introducing Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html)