# jQuery is not being loaded in lightning component

Tags: lightning

As per documentation, we can use external resource as: `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.resourceName}" />`

We have added bootstrap and jQuery in our component. But today morning it suddenly stopped working and jQuery is not being loaded. (Please note that I have activated Locker services a week ago..not today)

```
<script data-locker-src="/resource/***/***/script/jquery-2.2.4.js" >
```

As we can see, src is changed to data-locker-src. When I inspect element and update it as 'src' it's again started working.

Any suggestion!!

Comment: Spring '17 maybe. Check the release notes.

Comment: Check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131438/lightning-script-src-attribute-rendered-as-data-src

Comment: Sorry guys, actually Spring ''17 enabled CSP- so we will not be able to use jquery externally from header but jQuery is available if you use in controller.js.  My problem is I am using bootstrap which requires jQuery but as jQuery is running internally - boostrap.js is not able to find jQuery and throwing error...Bootstrap require jQuery.............

Comment: Have you tried loading multiple resources as outlined [in this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm)?